# Shorten code to 1 line

Tags: java

Ok so I had a problem asking to rewrite this code within 1 line of code within the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
String s;
    boolean b;
    JOptionPane jop;

    jop = new JOptionPane();

    s = jop.showInputDialog("Enter your email address");
    b = s.matches(".*@.*\\..*");
    if (b)
    {
        System.out.println("Address Appears Valid");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Address is Invalid");
    }
}
```

And here is what I have done so far

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

   String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email address");

   System.out.println(s.matches(".*@.*\\..*") ? "Address Appears Valid" : "Address is Invalid" );
}
```

How can I shorten this code even further?? THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email address");

   System.out.println(s.matches(".*@.*\\..*") ? "Address Appears Valid" : "Address is Invalid" );
```

Into this:

```
System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email address").matches(".*@.*\\..*") ? "Address Appears Valid" : "Address is Invalid" );
```

After all, why store the value if you are just going to use it in the next line?

Comment: wow you guys response really quick thanks a lot guys im new to java and really appreicate all your help. thanks

Comment: No problem! Once you come to a decision, you can mark the question as answered by clicking the checkbox on the answer that helps you out most.

Comment: ok so i compiled the program but it doesnt seem to be compiling i seem to have screwed something up can you please let me know what it is. Im really new to java

Comment: package shortcode;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Shortcode {

    System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email address").matches(".*@.*\\..*") ? "Address Appears Valid" : "Address is Invalid" );

}
also the error says <identifier> expected Im sure my error is something silly can you please help me out i cant seem to get it no matter how much i look at it

Comment: @user3422396 Try adding `public static void main (String[] args) {` just after `public class Shortcode {`, and add an `}` to the end of the file.

Comment: lol im so embarrased i was looking so hard for something like forgetting to import something in that I cant believe i forgot to put in the main method i guess thats what i get for trying to do homework at 2 in the morning and ty so much time to pack it and bury my head in my pillow so embarrassed XD

Comment: @user3422396 Don't worry about it. We're here to help out out :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't create s, pur joption in the println instead

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
   System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email address").matches(".*@.*\\..*") ? "Address Appears Valid" : "Address is Invalid" ));
}
```

Important point to note is that the input dialog box returns a string that you are only using once. So no need to store it instead use it just as it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all CR/LF characters from your source :)